# Python Maya: access result of a function when called in button flag

Tags: python, maya

I am working on UI window with a browse button. I have a browsePath function that I am calling in a cmds.button command. How can I get the output of browsePath() in my main function?

```
def main():
   cmds.button(label='Browse', command=browsePath)
def browsePath(*args):
   path = cmds.fileDialog2(fm=2)
   if path:
       cmds.textField('txt', tx=path[0])
   return path
```

Comment: print the returned path? `print cmds.button(label='Browse', command=browsePath)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so maya gui events return anything, you probaly need to relay on a variable outside. But since you already getting the path value to your textField you can always query the textField value where you want.